# USB peripheral: connecting USB shield to GND?

Tags: usb, ground, emc, earth, shield

I have read through many recommendations articles, and many StackExchange questions, but haven't come up with any clear understanding as there are many conflicting information out there. The simple question is, should a USB shield be connected to GND? If yes, should it be connected directly, through a resistor, or through a capacitor?

My case: Computer peripheral with a metal enclosure and USB-C connector. The thing however is, I **cannot guarantee** that everyone will use **shielded USB cables** to connect the device. Of course, I can make shielded cable a requirement in the manual, but I'd rather be predicting.

What I've read and tried to take into consideration:

- Using metal enclosure as EMI shield (both radiated and received)
- Using metal enclosure as ESD shield (safe ESD path away from the electronics)
- Apparently, some motherboards do have tied GND to Shield on the host end, and some don't

Comment: All USB cables are shielded I think, so are you saying you cannot guarantee that the users of your USB PC peripheral will not necessarily use USB cables to make the connection?

Comment: @tobalt USB cables are certainly not always shielded. About a third of all cables I tested were not shielded. Users must use a USB cable, but I can't guarantee they will use shielded ones. And even if all USB cables were shielded, I still don't know if the user's motherboard has tied shield to GND on the host end.

Comment: Did you look up the shielding requirements in the USB standard? What does it say?

Comment: There's no such thing as an unshielded "USB" cable. If it were, it wouldn't be USB.

Comment: @TimWilliams To be fair, there is such thing as unshielded USB cable. They just are used in low-speed devices and are non-detachable. So any detachable USB **cable assembly** with plugs on both ends **should**, by specification, be shielded. Of course, the non-shielded ones, if they exist, cannot be officially called USB cables.

Comment: @Justme Precisely!

Comment: Could you please check this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389972/usb-shield-to-ground-or-not-to-ground?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Is your device is connecting to an external device beyond the USB host? If so, is a ground loop a potential problem to the functioning of the device (sensitive analog signals, etc)? In that case, if you can't force the user to wire in a particular way you should consider adding a USB isolator and incorporate an isolated power supply into the device. Otherwise people are going to plug it in wrong and complain that it doesn't work. Hell, I've done that and I have design experience. Conversely if a ground loop doesn't matter (and often they're tolerable), let it be.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think there's a lot of conflicting information, but rather a lot of information that depends on context or EMC notions.

To understand, it's important not to confuse these symbols. Zero volt (equipotentiality), ground chassis (EMC) and earth (safety).

[image]

The general vision is as follows :

In theory, shielding can be floating. If it is hermetically sealed, the Faraday cage effect is obtained and the common-mode currents are drained off by parasitic capacitances.

[image]

Sometimes for safety reasons (class I devices requirements, reducing the accumulation of static electricity, ...) the enclosure must be earthed, and the parasitic capacitance (enclosure/earth) disappears, improving the efficiency of common-mode current evacuation.

[image]

In your electronic design, you always have to deal with the problem of internal EMC, and the parasitic capacitance between the printed circuit board and the metal enclosure is not ideal. A solution consist to connect directly the zero volt to the ground enclosure.

[image]

That's a general view of the problem ! There's a lot to be said for compromises in context. For example, if the two devices are in different buildings and with different earths, this configuration poses a problem because the 0V would be different. There's also a lot to say about one-point grounding or multipoint grounding inside the enclosure versus distributed stray capacitances in HF. The ground loop influence, etc...

Comment: …and this awesome book by Henry Ott covers your "etc...": [Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering](https://www.wiley.com/en-be/Electromagnetic+Compatibility+Engineering-p-9780470189306)

Comment: "For safety reasons, the enclosure must be earthed" says who?  Or are you saying to design a device that will work in a circuit having earthed enclosures, even if not all such enclosures will be grounded to earth?

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that sentence works better with a "sometimes" at the beginning :)

Comment: @hobbs, you're right. I will edit my message and add "sometimes (class I devices requirements or reducing the accumulation of static electricity, ...)"

Comment: @BenVoigt, I modified my message, but it was an example. The earth is optional for good EMC as in aircraft.

Comment: The different symbols are not always used in the way you want them to be used.

Comment: Also, the English language has a clear distinction between "security" (protection from bad people) and "safety" (protection from accidents); earth ground is obviously for safety, not security

Comment: It's a good post, but I am afraid it doesn't answer the question, because you present both choices of the OP as legitimate. IMO: with a proper USB cable, there is no need to connect 0V to the chassis in their USB device.

Comment: @user253751, you're right, I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm french and in my language is a same. I have modified my original message.

Comment: I still don't think it answers the question. There's many ways how it could be connected, based on a lot of things. But USB Type-C specification mandates how to connect it and there is only one way to connect it.

Comment: @Justme, In this document https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf : "The receptacle connectors should be connected to metal chassis or enclosures through grounding fingers, screws, or any other way to manage EMC." Like any cable shield, in fact, otherwise the shield is no longer effective at HF. However, as I said at the end of my message, it's the connection of the 0V to the chassie that will be different depending on the context (directly, by ferrite bead or capacitor and parallel resistor)

Comment: @Vincent It does say that, but the question asks, should the receptacle shell be connected to ground, and for that question, the answer is simply yes, directly.

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a simple answer in generic case so that is why you read conflicting information because the correct answer how to connect it depends on many things.

However, since your device has Type-C receptacle, the Type-C standard mandates that receptacle shell shall be connected to the PCB ground plane.

Comment: Can you link to where in the specification this is mentioned?

Comment: @Tinsa Please read whatever is the current version of the applicable standard from USB website. Type-C cable and connector specification.

Answer (score 5):

You'll hear plenty of people arguing about this online, but only in outdated discussions. ["USB Type-C Cable and Connector Specification" Release 2.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A139%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C720%2C0%5D) says in the notes to Table 3-11:

> Shield and GND grounds shall be connected within the USB Type-C plug
> on both ends of the cable assembly.

I've tested the continuity on a few different real USB-C cables so I've also observed this first-hand. **Even if you don't connect your shield and ground on your device's connector, the USB-C cable will do it for you.**

Comment: The standard also says that receptacle shell must be connected to ground.

Comment: @mjt I don't think it's outdated, because technically that spec only applies to USB-C, whereas a great many people (especially on this forum) still use other USB connectors, because they don't need USB C features.

Comment: That table (Table 3-11 USB 2.0 Type-C Standard Cable Assembly Wiring) is only for USB2.0 cables using Type-C connectors though. I have not yet found any reference in that document to USB3.X regarding GND and shield.

Comment: @Tinsa OK, but have you tried to search? That would be specified in Table 3-10 note 6 right above it on the previous PDF page. Use the search functionality to find text  from PDF files, maybe CTRL-F depending on which PDF reader you are using and on which platform.

Answer (score 3):

I always connect USB port shields to GND. Even when designing PCBs, you can see on their footprints, that shield pins are connected to the ground plane. This is common practise for handling USB port shields, I even use USB ports as a ground source when testing something on microcontrollers like ESP32 or Arduino. It is much easier to place the GND probe on the USB port rather than on some pin, which you might accidentally short with +5V.
Connect shielding directly to GND no need for resistor or capacitor.